# Javascript - How to get all matching classes and selector from css files for an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

It's a little hard to explain what I want to do, So I'll try to do it with an example.
Lets say I have this HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li id="myli" class="myclass">Hello</li>
</ul>
```

and the following css

```
.myclass{
   color:red;       
}
li.myclass{
   background-color:black;
}
ul li{
   float:left;
}
```

Now, I want to create a function in JS that get a DomElement and gets all the matching selectors from the css files for this element (like the F12 toolbar in chrome that shows all styles for an element) like the following:

```
var mySelectors = GetSelectorsForElement(document.getElementById("myli"));
```

and the content of mySelectors will be

```
[".myclass",
 "li.myclass",
 "ul li"]
```

Can this be achieved in JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the way you described it, it looks like you'll already have the id,  if you also wanted to get the classes, you could do something like this:

```
window.getMatchedCSSRules(document.getElementById("id"));
```

Comment: Note that this is only supported by Webkit browsers, so not IE / Firefox / Opera / etc.

Comment: Tried this on this page window.getMatchedCSSRules(document.getElementById("content")) and got null

Comment: What browser are you running it in?

Comment: Chrome, that command works but not everytime, can't point on when it is working and when not. But still, when it works, it gives me everything I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the Webkit-native `getMatchedCSSRules` because of (lack of) browser support, you could simply try the following function:

```
function css(a) {
    var sheets = document.styleSheets, o = [];
    for (var i in sheets) {
        var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
        for (var r in rules) {
            if (a.is(rules[r].selectorText)) {
                o.push(rules[r].selectorText);
            }
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HP326/

Adapted from [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, also a great way!

Answer (score 0):

```
window.getMatchedCSSRules(document.getElementById("myli"));
```

Comment: Note that this is only supported by Webkit browsers, so not IE / Firefox / Opera / etc.